# Getting "Unexpected token f" when use curl to parse JSON to my node app

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, curl, mean-stack

I am trying to test my app, the model is given below. I'm following tutorial from a book on the MEAN stack I am now stuck trying to do a post to save user data in mongo. Whenever I try to "curl" my JSON(in the command prompt):

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"firstName":"First", "lastName":"Last","email":"user@example.com","username":"username","password":"password"}" localhost:3050/users
```

I am getting this error:

```
POST /users 400 0.582 ms - 995
SyntaxError: Unexpected token f in JSON at position 1
```

Here is my model, controller and routing file (respectively):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
email: {
    type: String,
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, "Please fill a valid e-mail address"]
},
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: 'Username is required',
    trim: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    validate: [
        function(password) {
            return password && password.length > 6;
        }, 'Password should be longer'
    ]
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Controller:

```
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
var user = new User(req.body);
user.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        res.json(user);
    }
});
};
```

Routing file:

```
var users = require('../controllers/user.server.controllers');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.route('/users').post(users.create)
    .get(users.list);
};
```

Would really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: have you tried using single quotes inside object ?
For Example :
 "{'firstName':'First', 'lastName':'Last','email':'user@example.com','username':'username','password':'password'}" localhost:3050/users

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping your speech marks in the JSON data:

e.g. -X POST -d "{\"firstName\":\"First\"}"  etc.